# git - get only changed files from specific commit

Tags: git

Let's imagine tree something like this:

```
       d---g---i           feature 1
      /         \
     /   c---f   \         feature 2
    /   /     \   \
---a---b---e---h---j---n   master
            \         
             k---l---m     feature 3
```

In this repository, there are mix of files (sql, xml, dll...). Now, I would like to list only changed (or added) files from features 1 and 2 and 3 (well, feature 3 is not finished, but I need to take changed scripts and apply it to some customer to test it). I really need **only changed files**, because reapplying all scripts from whole repository to the customer is not possible.

Comment: Changes are *with respect to* something. Each commit is purely standalone, so to turn a commit into changes, you must pick some *other* commit and then diff the two commits. For instance, if you diff commit `i` against commit `g` (`git diff g i`), you will see what you changed going from `g` to `i`. The main problem you have here is that each feature branch starts from a different starting-point, so there is no obvious correct starting point for this process—but in fact, the *correct* starting point is going to be what the customer has today.

Comment: I think, that if I make difference between first commit of master branch and last commit on specific branche I got thise files. So for feature 1: git diff a i, for feature 2: git diff b f and for feature 3 git diff e m. But, the problem for me is, how to find these commits. I don't want to study whole log, if there will be about 100 features. But, maybe I have bad thinking about this strategy.

Comment: all you need is commit that customer have (say h) and commit you want to test (say m). `git diff --stat h m` will give changed file between the two.

Comment: @David: a common practice is to *tag* a specific revision (aka commit), and have the customer report that revision. Then you know they have `v2.2` (whatever commit hash that translates into), and then you know that to give them some specific fix or feature, you would compare it against, or build it as as special customer-specific branch, *atop* `v2.2`.

Comment: I'm still thinking, which strategy should be best for us. We have our testing environment, customer has testing environment and product environment. The biggest problem is, that every feature has to be approved (just if testing is OK) in our test environment and then in customer environment in **different order**. So, if customer wants feature 1, which contains feature 2, which customer don't want to apply, I don't know, how to get files only from feature 1. That's why I'm thinking, how to get only changed files from specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

Each commit is a complete snapshot of the repository.

so `git diff h m` will give you the raw difference between the two commits `h` and `m`, nothing but changes between the two.

Combine this with --stat or --name-only to get the files that are changed.

Comment: That's true, but in case of repository with let's say 100 features, it will be hard, to find right commits and make difference. Because, I don't want to simply make difference between feature 2 and dev. I want to make difference between commits **b and f**. This will return changes, which was done only in feature 2. In my thinking, feature is set of changed files. And I want to know, which changes were made in speficic feature, because similar changes I could make in other repository or these files I can apply to the customer as new feature. But, maybe I understand git for our projects bad :-)